# The error appears: Could not find method compileOptions() for arguments [build_88ddjipq2tquhqjwgj0asxwi4$_run_closure3@5ddee9dd]

Tags: java, android

Me aparece este error:

> Could not find method compileOptions() for arguments
>   [build_88ddjipq2tquhqjwgj0asxwi4$_run_closure3@5ddee9dd] on project
>   ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.,en mi build.grade

Y no se cómo solucionarlo. ¿Alguna idea?

Os dejo el código de mi `build.grade`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.3.0'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El compile options esta mal colocado debería ser así

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Gracias era eso!

Comment: De nada, deberías asignarla como respuesta correcta por si alguien tiene el mismo problema pueda localizarlo